# Receive a list in XML

Tags: java, jaxb

I want to convert this main XML tag with several inner list:

```
<statuses>
        <status code="201.0000" description="....." severity="information"/>
        <status code="200.1077" description="....." severity="information"/>
        <status code="200.1077" description="....." severity="information"/>
</statuses>
```

I tried this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "payment")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class mainXML {

    @XmlElement(name = "statuses")
    public List<Statuses> statuses;
    ....
}
```

**// Inner object**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Statuses {

    @XmlElement(name = "status")
    private Status status;    
    .....
}
```

**// Inner object**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Status {   

    @XmlElement(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String code;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String severity
    .........
}
```

But I get

```
    <statuses>
        <status code="500.1072" description="....." severity="warning"/>
    </statuses>
```

Do you know how to properly implement several tags `status` into the main tag `statuses`?

I get the response using WebFlux and I print the XML using this code:

```
//Create JAXB Context
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(EnrolCheckResponse.class);

            //Create Marshaller
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

            //Required formatting??
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

            //Print XML String to Console
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

            //Write XML to StringWriter
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(employee, sw);

            //Verify XML Content
            String xmlContent = sw.toString();
            System.out.println(xmlContent);
```

Comment: Post the code of your XML parser

Comment: I posted the code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need an intermediate "Statuses" class, JAXB already knows what a list means.

Instead, set the name of Status' XmlRootElement, so JAXB will know what nodes to expect inside of "statuses"

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "payment")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class mainXML {

    @XmlElement(name = "statuses") // name of the wrapper
    public List<Status> statuses;
    ...
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "status")  // name of a single node
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public static class Status {

    @XmlElement(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String code;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String description;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String severity;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@XmlElementWrapper` does what you want. `@XmlElement` is used for each entry in statuses. `@XmlElementWrapper` is used to wrap them in a single tag.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "payment")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class mainXML {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name="statuses")
    @XmlElement(name = "status")
    public List<Statuses> statuses;
    ....
}
```